# In Object refer to itself anonymous function key Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this object:

```
var crudConfig = function($wizard, $formModal, $deleteModal) {

'use strict';

return {


    handleOnShowFormModal : function() {

        $formModal.on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
               ...................
                    this.fillForms(data);
               ....................
        });

        return this;
    },
    fillForms : function(data) {
        //do stuff
        return this;
    }
 }
}
```

The problem appears when I call the fillForms with the param.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.fillForms is not a function
```

As the fillForms key is an anonymous function how can I call it from inside the object? On other relative questions I only found how to refer itself if the key has a string value and the I call like this: `this.fillForms` .

Comment: You should use a constructor instead of factory function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` within the callback references the `$formModal` element. What you need to do is store `this` that refer to the object in a variable before the event listener is called and use the variable within the callback to access the object.

Just like this:

```
handleOnShowFormModal : function() {
  var _this = this
  $formModal.on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    _this.fillForms(data); 
  });

  return this;
},
```

Comment: You are welcome. There are other ways of solving this issue like using binding the object this to that of the callback. But, this is the easiest.

Comment: Would be great for me to learn if you can show me an example ... :)

Comment: Oh, check the link in @melpomene's comment on your question. The accepted answer has detailed information.